# Play video from inputstream by using java or javsacript

Tags: javascript, jsp, video-streaming, html5-video

Is it possible to play a video file which is received as an input stream from the server in a jsp page either by using java or javascript

Comment: Yes, the process should be possible. What issue are you having?

Comment: @guest271314 I didnt find any examples showing how to achieve that

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081377/unable-to-stream-video-over-a-websocket-to-firefox

Comment: Its by using sockets which has a video url, but for me i have no video URL i have an inputstream with video

Comment: Is input stream requested from browser?

Comment: Nope when i request for video i will get an inputstream as response

Comment: Yes, what is input stream? You can continue adding buffers to playing video.

Comment: Its an inputstream object in java

Comment: Did you succeed to show the video you received?