# RTC Peer Connection - receiving stream twice

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have an instance of `RTCPeerConnection` with `ontrack` defined:

```
 newConnection.ontrack = receivedStream // remote
```

Once the SDP exchange is complete and the peer adds their local stream:

```
 connection.addStream(stream); // local
```

I see that `receivedStream` gets invoked twice per stream - Inspecting `e.track` shows me that the first invocation is for the `audio` track, and second is for the `video` track.

What's odd is that inspecting `e.streams[0]` and calling `getTracks` on this gives me two `MediaStreamTracks` - one for audio and another for video:

[image]

So I'm netting **four** `MediaStreamTracks` across **two** invocations of `receivedStream` despite calling  `addStream` once.

`receivedStream` is here:

```
 function receivedStream(e) {
        var stream = e.streams[0]; // this gets invoked twice when adding one stream!
        if (!stream) {
            throw new Error("no stream found");
        };
        // this gets me the corresponding connection
        waitForStream(stream.id).then(function (connection) {
            // get element
            targetVideoElement[0].srcObject = stream; // this now gets called twice per stream - once for audio, once for video
        }).catch(function (error) {
           // log
        });
    }
```

Comment: _"I don't recall this happening in previous implementations"_ Can you include the  code that you previously implemented at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 - it was old code that somehow successfully configured the `srcObject` of a target `<video>` element to output both audio and video; I don't recall how though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform the same procedure for each `MediaStreamTrack`, that is add the `MediaStreamTrack` to a `MediaStream` instance, then set `.srcObject` of `HTMLMediaElement`

```
const mediaStream = new MediaStream();

const video = document.querySelector("video");

for (const track of receivedMediaStream) {
  mediaStream.addTrack(track)
}

video.srcObject = mediaStream;
```

Comment: Thanks - though how do I go about pairing up the `video` and `audio` tracks then on the receiver side?  Do you know of any way to transmit a/v without having to orchestrate these pairs manually?

Comment: @SB2055 Not sure what you mean? You add each `MediaStreamTrack` to a `MediaStream` instance, each stream outputs media at `HTMLMediaElement`. If you receive the `MediaStream` itself, instead of individual `MediaStreamTrack`s you can set the `.srcObject` to the received `MediaStream`

Comment: I mean I have a `newConnection.ontrack = receivedStream` function that accepts the incoming `MediaStreamTrack`, though it looks like there's no way to know which `stream` they came from.  This means I need to tell `receivedStream` which `RtcPeerConnection` the stream is for, and then set up some kind of "wait" that says "when we have both audio and video tracks, push to the DOM".  Is this right?

Comment: Ah!  That's what I'd like - to receive the entire MediaStream instead of the tracks.  How can I do that to avoid the above complexity?

Comment: Can you include the remainder of your code at Question? Have you tried using [`RTCPeerConnection.getRemoteStreams()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getRemoteStreams) or `.getLocalStreams()`?

Comment: I don't know if it will help much, but I provided the `receive` body above.  The issue seems to relate to handling tracks vs MediaStreams.  I want to receive an entire MediaStream so I don't have to compose one.

Comment: At your updated code, you can check if `.srcObject` is `null`. If true store a reference to the `MediaStream`, set the `MediaStream` at `.srcObject`, else if false add the `MediaStreamTracks` from `MediaStream`s at subsequent calls to the existing `MediaStream` reference.

Comment: I understand that there's a way to handle individual tracks; I'm wondering how to avoid it in the name of simplicity.

Comment: You code appears to receive two or more `MediaStream`s. You can pass a `MediaStream` to the `MediaStream()` constructor, though following that add the `MediaStreamTrack`s to the existing `MediaStream` using `.addTrack()`, e.g., `const stream = mediaStreamReference; if (videoElement.srcObject === null) {
    videoElement.srcObject = mediaStreamReference
  } else {
    for (const track of nextMediaStream) {
  mediaStreamReference.addTrack(track)
}
}`

Comment: I'm really not sure how else to make this clear; I'm trying to avoid any manual orchestration of a + v.  I'd like to figure out how to receive a full MediaStream without manually handling or composing one with individual tracks.  With manual work comes more complexity and then I have to worry about what happens when I receive two audio and one video tracks for a given connection etc.  I'd rather just one-and-done it.

Comment: Your existing code appears to receive a full `MediaStream`, which you can set directly at the `.srcObject` of an `HTMLMediaElement`. If you want to add further tracks to the media playback add `MediaStreamTrack`s to the existing `MediaStream`, else you will need to reset the `.srcObject` to the new `MediaStream`, which will stop playback of previous stream. Another option would be to use `MediaSource` to play the media in the background, record the media, convert the resulting `Blob` to an `ArrayBuffer`, then call `.appendBuffer()` on `SourceBuffer`, but that is more code than at Answer

Comment: Yes I see that.  My issue is that this callback gets called twice per stream.  Inspecting `e.track` shows me one is of `kind: video` and the other is `kind: audio` however if I inspect `e.streams[0].getTracks()`, I see two tracks (a+v).  So I'm very confused about why I'm netting four tracks across two invocations of `receive` when I call `addStream` once.

Comment: A `MediaStream` can contain either one `MediaStreamTrack` or two `MediaStreamTrack`s. If you receive two distinct `MediaStream` objects, then you can set the first `MediaStream` as `.srcObject` of `HTMLMediaElement`, subsequent `MediaStream` object you can iterate and add each `MediaStreamTrack` to the existing `MediaStream`. Do not believe it is possible to add an entire `MediaStream` object to a `MediaStream` except at the call to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your patience - just added a screenshot to my question to demonstrate my confusion.

Comment: _"MediaStream()
Creates and returns a new MediaStream object. You can create an empty stream, a stream which is based upon an existing stream, or a stream that contains a specified list of tracks (specified as an array of MediaStreamTrack objects)."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream

Comment: Do `MediaStreamTrack`s of `e.stream` and `stream.getTracks()` have the same `id` for each audio and video kind? Or do you actually receive two distinct `MediaStream` objects?

Comment: yes both invocations of `receivedStream` are with equal `e.streams[0]` - the ids are the same for both tracks across both instances.

Comment: Then you can  check if the `HTMLMediaElement` `.srcObject` is `null`, if true set the value to the first `MediaStream`, else do nothing with second duplicate `MediaStream`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402263/how-to-send-getusermedia-recorded-stream-to-server-nodejs-realtime/. Then the question would arise as to why you are receiving, or appearing to receive duplicate `MediaStream` objects.

Comment: Yeah - thanks for the help around figuring that out.  Think I should post a new question now that we have more information?

Comment: @SB2055 Would would new Question consist of? Why you appear to be receiving duplicate `MediaStream` objects? Does current Answer and comments resolve present Question?

Comment: @SB2055, I am also getting the duplicate 'track' event. Can you please share how did you solve this?

Comment: Is it me or this answer is absolutely irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

May be you have added more than one track in remote peer like here:

```
localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, localStream));
```

Each call to peer.addTrack( ) in the remote Peer produces and event in local peer.ontrack = ()

Answer (score 1):

the `track` event is fired once for each MediaStreamTrack. Hence, if you have two different tracks, such as an audio and a video, in a MediaStream, the ontrack event will fire twice. The `stream` property of the event of both events will be identical and you can attach the stream to the same audio or video element twice without consequences.